# JAX-RS Swagger InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, rest, swagger, jax-rs, websphere

I am trying to create a servlet using Websphere application. My web.xml is this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>main.AppConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and my AppConfig is this:

```
public AppConfig() {
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
    beanConfig.setHost("localhost:9080");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
}
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    classes.add(Test.class);
    
    classes.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
    classes.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
    return classes;
}
```

but when I deploy the application I get this error at the line:

```
BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();

Resource class main.AppConfig can not be instantiated due to InvocationTargetException
```

which the `InvocationTargetException`'s target is `null`
Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

This `InvocationTargetException` is most likely caused by the convoluted stuff that WebSphere does while instantiating `AppConfig`, and is not telling you (or us) what the actual problem is.

`InvocationTargetException` is just a silly exception that the java runtime wraps other expressions with, for no reason other than to confuse programmers and make their life harder. (Well, they have some reasons that pretty much boil down to some sort of engineering nobility, which exists only in their minds, and for all practical purposes it is just annoyance with zero practical value.)

In order to find what the ***actual*** problem is, you will need to obtain the `cause` of that `InvocationTargetException`. You can do this in one of two ways:

- The primitive way: catch the exception, invoke `exception.getCause()`, and report the result
- The better way: have your debugger stop when the `InvocationTargetException` is thrown and examine its contents. There should be a `cause` member in there.

This will give you more insights as to exactly what went wrong.

Hopefully this answer will be found useful not only by you, but also by anyone else receiving an `InvocationTargetException`, either under the same circumstances, or under similar circumstances, or even under completely dissimilar circumstances: No matter what the circumstances are, the answer is to always look at the cause of the `InvocationTargetException`.

Comment: Error happens at the line 
`BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();` and the InvocationTargetException's target is null which makes no sense. I cant find what is throwing this error because I cant access it inside eclipse

Comment: Oh wow. An `InvocationTargetException` with a `null` target.  This really makes no sense.  I am sorry I am out of guesses.